# C++: operator overloading: in-class and out-class. Ambiguity with preincrement operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, pre-increment

Check it out [this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4bf8336b6146ca53):

```
struct A
{
    A operator+(A const& a) { cout << 1 << endl; return A(); }
    A& operator++() { cout << 2 << endl; return *this; }
    A operator++(int) { cout << 3 << endl; return *this; }
    bool operator!() { cout << 4 << endl; return true; }

};

A operator+(A const& a, A const& b)
{ cout << 5 << endl; return A(); }

A& operator++(A& a) { cout << 6 << endl; return a; }
A operator++(A const& a, int) { cout << 7 << endl; return A(); }
bool operator!(A const& a) { cout << 8 << endl; return false; }

int main()
{
    A a, b;

    a + b; // Prints 1 instead 5
    ++a;   // Ambiguity
    a++;   // Prints 3 instead 7
    !a;    // Prints 4 instead 8

    return 0;
}
```

In every case, the in-class overload of an operator is choosen against any other out-class overload of the same operator, but the preincrement operator is different: it causes an ambiguity between the in-class and out-class overload.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your post-increment member operator is not a `const` member, whereas the non-member one `const A&` parameter. There is no ambiguity, and the  non-const version chosen. The same does not apply for the pre-increment version. Both member and non-member bind to a non-const `A`, hence the ambiguity.

Look:

```
// non-const member. Does not require A operand to be const
A operator++(int)

// non-member. Requires A operand to be const
A operator++(A const& a, int)
```

Comment: This applies to the `+` and `!` operators as well. Declare the member functions `const`, and the corresponding calls become ambiguous.

Comment: Pretty obvious. I seem a rookie. By the way, why the non-const version is choosen against the non-member function? For being "less cv-qualified"? After all, a cv-comparision doesn't apply for member and non-member overloads. In my understanding, all forms (const/non-const member function) should provoke an ambiguity with non-class versions.

Comment: "After all, a cv-comparision doesn't apply for member and non-member overloads." I'm not sure what exactly that means, but it could be the source of misunderstanding.

Comment: @Peregring-lk Non-const overloads are chosen in this case because `a` is not `const` and the rules of the language state those overloads are preferred over `const` ones, all other things equal.

Comment: I meant: in order to choose an overload (for a regular function-member, not an operator), if an object is non-const, binding to a const version requeries a const-conversion, so, the non-const version is a best match if both exist. Now, concerning operators, we haven't two const/non-const member operator overloads, but two member/non-member operators. What I don't understand is why the member version is a better match than the non-member one (when parameters are the same). Are there rules stating it explicity (member operator best), or does it happen due to a different reason?

Comment: @Peregring-lk Because the members don't have a `const` operand that the non-members do.

Comment: Non-member functions/operators can't be const qualified. It has no sense at all. So, a comparision between then, using cv qualifications as discriminant, has no sense again.

Comment: @Peregring-lk Non members can have const parameters. The corresponding parameters of the member versions are not const, because the members aren't const.

Comment: Ok, I see. You meant all the time the implicit parameter: if the member overload is `const`, the implicit parameter -the first one, is also `const`, as it happens in the non-member version.